# how to Update query in MySql to my Custome String

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

how to Mysql Update to my Custome String

i use this Query for find Num post for any blog for user.

i have 14K users and 500K Post.

sample i use userId 152.

```
SELECT
  user.email,
  user.`id`,
  post.`blog_id`,
  post.domain,
  post.`user_id`,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `user`
  INNER JOIN post
    ON post.`user_id` = user.id
    WHERE user.id = 152
GROUP BY post.`blog_id`
```

result:

```
    id  blog_id  user_id  COUNT(*)  
------  -------  -------  ----------
   152      152      152         105
   152      170      152          41
   152      222      152           6
   152    23552      152         104
   152    24053      152           5
   152    27567      152           7
```

but i need to update in user Table > field numPost to this String

```
({"blog Id": "num of post"}) => `({"152":105,"170":41,"222":6,"23552":104,"24053":5,"27567":7})`
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have your json this format

```
'{"152":105,"170":41,"222":6,"23552":104,"24053":5,"27567":7}';
```

you could decode

```
$myArray = json_decode('{"152":105,"170":41,"222":6,"23552":104,"24053":5,"27567":7}');
```

and loop over the array

```
foreach ( $myArray as $key =$value){
     $connection->createCommand()->update('user', 
                    ['blod_id' => $value],['id' => $key])->execute();
}
```

Comment: no i need my result Query to this JSON for save in Table user field numPost

Comment: which version of mysql you are using ?

Comment: MySQL version 5.5.31

Comment: if you have mysq. 5.5 you have not  function for manage JSON in sql .. (in mysql 5.7 there is specific functionfor JSON) so i think that you should use a solution like in my answer